# How to join array elements in pairs in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a array of numbers [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and I want to make it into a string like this: '1,2 3,4 5,6 7,8 9,10'. Is there some fast and simple vay to do this in javascript or do i have to use the loop?

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     if(i%2 == 0){
        res += array[i] + ',';
     } else {
        res += array[i] + ' ';
     }
}
```

Comment: There might be more *elegant* ways, but your current approach probably can't be beaten in terms of speed, code length, and general complexity I think

Comment: Looks like no one's reading your question, *5* completely incorrect answers :P

Comment: @CertainPerformance well 2 now. And one more as I was typing this

Comment: Oh, though you could golf the alternate `','` `' '`s into the conditional operator, removing the `if`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the result you desire:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    .reduce((acc, val, idx) => 
        idx % 2 === 0 
            ? (acc ? `${acc} ${val}` : `${val}`) 
            : `${acc},${val}`, '') 
// "1,2 3,4 5,6 7,8 9,10"
```

By taking advantage of the third parameter of the reduce function we know the index of the element we are currently iterating over, therefore also making this function work for arrays that aren't numbers 1 through 10.

Answer (score 0):

You could get pairs with comma and then join the array with spaces for the string, but you need still a loop

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    temp = [],
    i = 0,
    string;
    
while (i < array.length) {
    temp.push(array.slice(i, i += 2).join());
}

string = temp.join(' ');

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chunk the array, and join the elements with commas and spaces:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

chunkArr = arr.reduce((acc, item, index) => { 
  const i = Math.floor(index/2)
  if(!acc[i]) {
    acc[i] = []
  }
  acc[i].push(item)
  return acc
}, [])

arr = chunkArr.map(arr => arr.join(',')).join(' ')

console.log(arr)
```

> Note, this code works with an odd amount of numbers too.