# Print all the elements of an array with text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array that consists of numbers and letters. Each number corresponds to a letter, there's a colon between each number and letter this is the format of the output `1:A`

Here's my array: 
`var filteredProps = ["1", "A", "2", "B"]`.
I want the first element in the array to match up with the second element so for example, an output would look like this `1:A`. What I am trying to achieve is an output like this:

This array has the following numbers and letters `1:A 2:B`

This is my array `var filteredProps = ["1", "A", "2", "B"]`
so far I've accomplished to get this format I want by creating the following alert

```
window.alert("This array has the following numbers and letters " + filteredProps[0] + ":" + filteredProps[1] + " " + filteredProps[2] + ":" + filteredProps[3])
```

As you can see in my code above I specify every single position in the array but this won't work if my array grows and there are some additions to it.

I'm not sure what approach I should take here, I played around a little with `for` loops and `foreach` but couldn't quite achieve the behaviour I want. Can someone help please?

Comment: See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56699468/763026

Comment: `filteredProps.reduce((p, c, i) => p + (i % 2 === 0 ? " " : ":") + c);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's your solution:

```js
var filteredProps = ["1", "A", "2", "B"];
let message = 'This array has the following numbers and letters';
for (let index = 0; index < filteredProps.length; index += 2) {
    message += ` ${filteredProps[index]}:${filteredProps[index + 1]}`;
}
window.alert(message);
```

Comment: console.log is nicer than window.alert

Comment: @Barmar The OP wants to use an alert, not really relevant to the problem anyways